# Уточнение в обращении

Tags: уточнения

Помогите разобраться. У нас на работе есть тёзки, допустим, имя обоих — Пётр. Допустим, фамилия одного Иванов, второго — Сидоров.

Я пишу следующее предложение:

"Пётр, Иванов, всплыла ещё одна проблема".

Я ставлю запятую после Пётр, подразумевая, что Иванов — это уточнение и выделяется запятыми с обеих сторон.

Допустима ли такая конструкция?

Answer (score 2):

В принципе для внутренней переписки такой вариант возможен, другой вариант: **Пётр (Иванов)**, всплыла ещё одна проблема.

Обращения могут уточняться, например: Молодой человек, **в гимнастёрке**, подойдите сюда!

В устной речи может уточняться фамилия: **Катя, Иванова,** я к тебе обращаюсь.

Answer (score 2):

В публичной переписке такая пунктуация выглядит излишней: для однозначности достаточно обратиться по имени и фамилии (**Петр Иванов,** ...). Но при передаче устной речи такое вполне возможно, поскольку говорящий мог не сразу заметить необходимость в уточнении (обычно это отражается на интонации), и эту особенность речи можно передать.

Answer (score 0):

Такое уточнение не характерно для письменной речи. Вы ведь не писатель, который стремится передать речь персонажа. К тому же есть место для неверного понимания: а вдруг Петр и Иванов - два разных человека. Если хотите сделать ваше письменное обращение неформальным, используйте скобки: **Пётр (Иванов), всплыла ещё одна проблема.**